# How to negate a validation rule? laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-validation

I am currently using custom validation rule in my **AppServiceProvider.php**.

```
Validator::extend('driver_assigned', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    //more code here
});
```

I don't think its a good idea to create another one for `driver_unassigned`.

```
Validator::extend('driver_unassigned', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    //more code here
});
```

---

I may be wondering if there is a laravel validation rule that could do negation something like below to lessen the coding.

```
'driver_id' => 'not:driver_assigned',
'image_id' => 'not:image'
```

How to negate the result of all validation rule?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [different](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-different) validation rule

```
'driver_id' => 'different:driver_assigned',
'image_id' => 'different:image'
```

Comment: Already to that. it does not negate the result. It is another rule that check if the field is different. In my case, it always failing. Thanks for the reply though

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using `unique` validation rule, instead of creating your own validation rule. Assuming that you have table `drivers` and field `driver_id` where you store unique driver ids:

```
'driver_id' => 'unique:drivers,driver_id'
```

This way, Laravel will check in the table `drivers` if given `driver_id` input doesn't have a record still.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique